# SQL Server : Simulate Long I/O in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I was reading about I/O delays & the error message 833 in the error log in SQL Server. How do I simulate a long I/O scenario so I can get this error message in the log. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it difficult to get the 833 error message in the SQL error log using T-SQL alone if your I/O subsystem is appropriately sized.  However, if you stress the I/O subsystem using SQLIO (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20163) or SQLIOSIM (on SQL install media) and run I/O intensive queries at the same time, that might generate the error.

Below is a T-SQL script to create and load a test table, along with an I/O intensive query.  Run multiple instances of the SELECT loop in different SSMS windows if needed.

```
--create test table
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable(
      Col1 nchar(4000) NOT NULL
    , Col2 nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
    );

--load 10000 rows (about 2.8GB)
WITH 
    t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    ,t16M AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t256 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000), REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 100000;
GO

--run query in loop (expect parallel execution plan with many read-ahead and LOB page reads)
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @RowCount int, @Iteration int = 1;
WHILE @Iteration <= 100
BEGIN
    CHECKPOINT;
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE Col2 LIKE 'X%';
    RAISERROR('Iteration %d completed',0,1,@Iteration) WITH NOWAIT; --display progress message
    SET @Iteration += 1;
END;
GO
```

**EDIT:**
I ran across another I/O test tool developed by Microsoft, DiskSpd, and was able to produce the error reliably on my test system in conjunction with the above T-SQL script.  This open-source tool is a free download available from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223.  DiskSpd has the same functionality as SQL but is a bit easier to use, more well documented, and has the option to produce XML output to facilitate analysis.

The parameters I used for the test are below.  The error was produced within 30 seconds after starting the test with the SQL Server data file also on the D drive.

```
diskspd.exe" -h -d60 -c1G -F32 -w50 -r -b8K -o1000 -L "D:\DiskSpd.dat"
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But, am finding it difficult to understand what you are doing in the section under 'WITH' (i.e. below '--load 10000 rows (about 2.8GB)') ... from 'WITH' until 'GO'. Can you please explain them? Sorry for the trouble. Couldn't get : 1) what is t(n), 2) What are you doing by 'cross join'?

Comment: @Jean, the queries defined under the `WITH` clause are common table expressions (CTEs) that are referenced and reused by name.  I use those here to create the 100000 row test table.  The `t4` CTE returns a 4 row single-column table, the `t256` CTE cross joins to t4 4 times to produce 256 rows (4*4*4*4) and the `tt6M' CTE similarly joins to `t256` to produce 16M rows used as the source for the `INSERT`. The `t(n)` specifies the name of the table and column alias for the row constructor literals, required for syntax but not used here.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx.

Comment: no matter how hard I tried with the query you gave (with even 100,000 records' insertion) running for more than two days, SQL Server didn't throw the error 833. Any help please?

Comment: @Jean, were you running and intensive SQLIO test concurrently during the SQL script?

Comment: yes. I was running SQLIOSim tests. Along with it, in parallel, I opened multiple windows in SSMS & ran the script you suggested (in fact, each with 100,000 records and not just 10,000). Still in vain! Please help!

Comment: @Jean, much will depend on the speed and health of the I/O system.  It looks like your subsystem is healthy enough to avoid the error even under load, which is a good thing. Let me see if I can come up with a way to reliably produce the error on an otherwise health storage subsystem.

Comment: @Jean, I found another disk testing tool that might better help you produce the error and updated my answer accordingly.  My apologies for the taking so long to get back.  Thanks for your patience..

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar to below, Which will generate lot of IO load on SQL LOG & Data Drives.

1. Create simple [TestTable] with couple of fields
2. Insert the rows into above table continuously by any of the following code

   ```
   INSERT INTO [TestTable] VALUES ('Sample data')
   GO 10000
   ```

After 10,000 inserts above query execution completes.
OR

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [TestTable] VALUES ('Sample data')
END
GO
```

This query will keep on running until stopped explicitly.

Comment: Cool, didn't know you could do that. Neither can intellisense, apparently :P

Comment: The problem with the suggested test is that the actual I/O operations will be very small, naively I'd say it will only write 1 page (8k) in the db-file and another in the log. (+ some overhead; + some indexes if you have any, + ... ). You might want to try to insert bigger sets in 1 operation to actually put some load on the system and then do these in parallel. A tool like SQLIO, as suggested by Steve Ford, will automate that kind of tests for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at using the free Microsoft SQLIO tool that can be used to benchmark disk performance. This would put load on your disks which hopefully will enable you to see the errors in your environment.

Details here:
[Brent Ozar article on finding SAN Bottlenecks](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/09/finding-your-san-bottlenecks-with-sqlio/)
[SQL IO, Powershell and storage performance](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2013/03/28/sqlio-powershell-and-storage-performance-measuring-iops-throughput-and-latency-for-both-local-disks-and-smb-file-shares.aspx)
[SQLIO Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20163)

You also might try the SQLIOSim utility which uses random patterns, so is not repeatable. It is a stress-testing tool.

Comment: SQLiOSim seems the right utility am looking for! Let me check on it & get back!

Comment: @Jean, you will need to run some queries that require I/O while the I/O subsystem is being stressed by the tool in order to get the error message in the SQL Server error log.

Comment: Thanks, @DanGuzman ! Any examples to such queries please? Google search is only giving articles on how to detect I/O issues. Sorry, am a newbie trying to learn this. Apologize if my question is stupid.